# typeahead Autocomplete Throwing error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, typeahead.js

Hi I am trying to implement Auto Complete Text Box using "typeahead.js" something like http://sriniavatar.com/bootstrap-typeahead-in-asp-net-mvc/ in my MVC Project

My Script are bellow

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var substringMatcher = function (strs) {
        return function findMatches(q, cb) {
            var matches, substringRegex;               
            matches = [];                
            substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');                
            $.each(strs, function (i, str) {
                if (substrRegex.employees(str)) {
                    matches.push(str);
                }
            });

            cb(matches);
        };
    };

    $.post('/Employee/TagSearch', null, function (data) {
        var employees = data;
        $('#sriniavatar').typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
        },
        {
            name: 'employees',
            displayKey: 'value',
            source: substringMatcher(employees)
        });
    });
```

And My Employee Controller's TagSearch Method is given bellow

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TagSearch(string term)
    {
        DataAccess db = new DataAccess();
        var employees = db.GetEmployeesName().ToList();
        //if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(term))
        //{
        //    employees = employees.Where(e => e.Surname.Contains(term.Trim())
        //    || e.ForeName.Contains(term.Trim())
        //    || e.Win_UserName.Contains(term.Trim())
        //    ).ToList();
        //}
        return Json(employees, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Now **Problem is that when I am running programme its showing following Error *"Unhandled exception at line 95, column 21 in http://localhost:57512/Employee/ViewEmployees

0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'employees'"*** 

even though I have referenced following the scripts in my project

```
    <link href="~/Content/typeahead.css" rel="stylesheet" />        <script "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script> <script src="~/Scripts/typeahead.js"></script> <br/>...Page Contents...<br>
    <script src="~/Scripts/typeahead.mvc.model.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of any JavaScript that has an employees method with regExp

```
if (substrRegex.employees(str)) {    
                ^^^^^^^^^
```

I believe you want [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

```
if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
```